# What is difference between Ln and Log?

Tags: calculus

We are currently learning logarithms.

I have seen how in questions, people tend to use ln instead of log base 10. What is difference? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: ln usually denotes the logarithm base e. What log means, depends on the context. In school-like math, it usually means log base 10. In most of the scientific literature, it means log base e (ln is mainly used in school math). Occasionally, it can also mean log base 2 (some computer science fields, sometimes also appreciated by ld). So, while the meaning of ln is pretty clear, you have to infer the base of log from the context.